# USB-device driver for HTC OneVX (USB debugging)

Tags: android, device-driver

I have a HTC One VX phone and I would like to develop an app for it.

I got the SDK, IDE, JDK and everything I need. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html I tried to run my app on my phone from eclipse. But my device is not showing up in the Android device chooser window. I'm guessing it is because I do not have the driver for the phone, but I can't seem to find it.

I have my phone set for "**USB debugging**".

The site -> http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Drivers

Says to install the OEM USB driver for my computer. I have a dell that I have upgraded to Windows 7, service tag BLZXLC1. My so I can't get the drivers from the site because I have upgraded my OS.

But I already have the USB drivers right? In the device manager I have a "Android Phone" under "Other devices" which doesn't have a driver for it. What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Try running the debug feature and reinstalling USB driver

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Download and install **HTC Sync Manager** from HTC:
http://www.htc.com/www/software/htc-sync-manager/download/

Apart from being the official Sync program for HTC devices, it also contains the necessary `USB device drivers` for Windows, to use with (USB) `Android Debug Bridge` (*ADB*).

HTC Sync Manager supports the following devices (current as of *February 9th, 2013*):

HTC J Butterfly, HTC Droid DNA, HTC One VX, HTC One SV, HTC One X+, HTC One S Special Edition, HTC Desire X, HTC One SC, and HTC One SU, HTC One X, HTC One XL, HTC One XC, HTC One S, HTC One V, HTC EVO 4G LTE, HTC Droid Incredible 4G, HTC J, HTC Desire C, HTC Desire VC, HTC Desire V

Comment: Not sure why this question got down voted but anyways I figured out a solution. http://junefabrics.com/android/download.php install that program it contains the drivers needed. I'm assuming the HTC Sync Manager will work too. But if not use the link I gave.

Comment: If that (PdaNet+) works for you - great, I've had nothing but trouble when trying that "shortcut" and always ended up installing the manufacturer drivers instead.

Comment: @rickster if your content is vague, or too narrow where it will not benefit a member or adhere to the Terms and Agreement; users will downvote based on the quality of your Answer or Question.

Answer (score 0):

the people who are facing the problem in connecting their htc phone with eclipse. they must install HTC-SYNC from the htc site. htc sync also include the usb debugging driver in it . just install and enjoy.
100% worked!!

Thats the link

### **http://www.htc.com/au/support/content.aspx?id=6196**

Answer (score 0):

Hi download this link only driver.HTC users with a device running Sense 3.6 or below, download either the version 4.5.0.001.exe or below versions.

[HTC Drivers](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/i2kfapzwunvgu/HTC)